# Is there a way I could write a list comprehension for these nested for loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Aim is to 'append' `(answer[x:y])` for each iteration to an empty list so I thought of list comprehension but the extra `if` statements and `for` loops confused me. Is there a better way to do this?

```
answer = "hippopotamus"
count_vowels= 0
count_consonants=0
 for x in range(len(answer)):
   if answer[x] in 'aeiou':
     for y in range(x,len(answer)):
        if x == y:
            continue
        print(answer[x:y])
        count_vowels+=1
```

Comment: Do you really want to try and make an unreadable mess out of this code? As a side note, `for y in range(x,len(answer)):    if x == y:  continue` is simply `for y in range(x+1, len(answer)):`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Well, what I want to do is generate a list with slices from each iteration, not necessarily force a one liner. Could be without comprehension. Final aim is to generate a list and remove duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

logic first for loop for 0 to len of answer.
then filter on answer[i] in "aeiou" then the nested for loop from i+1 to len of answer.
you can get the len of x to get count_vowels

```
x=[answer[i:y] for i in range(len(answer)) if answer[i] in 'aeiou' for y in range(i+1,len(answer))]
```